# Windows phone profiler, heap summary shows not a complete summary?

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7, profiling

Graph shows that it is used about 30 MBs of memory. However, Heap summary shows info for less than 1 MB (if looking at "retained allocations at end). What can be a reason for that, how to get the rest?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The profiler only shows you allocations done by managed code. Unfortunately, allocations can be done by native code too (for instance, when you load a picture), and those aren't traced by the profiler. This makes tracking memory leaks especially tricky on Windows Phone.

Comment: Exactly: i have tons of pictures, and need to debug them, as they took too many memory... maybe some 3rd party tools?

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko I think only trial and error can help you here, the third-party tools I know won't work on Windows Phone. This article could be useful too: http://blogs.codes-sources.com/kookiz/archive/2013/02/17/wpdev-memory-leak-with-bitmapimage.aspx