# Windows phone ListBox memory consumption

Tags: windows-phone-7, memory, mvvm-light

How can it be that short list with 20 items consumes 15 megabytes?

While running empty list, app consumes 23 MBs. When i'm filling list with 20 items (each item contains picture 40*40 and string with name), app consumes 35 MBs at the top of the list and 42 MBs at the bottom of the list.

Is that a normal behavior?

Comment: Start a memory profiling analysis from the debug menu to see what's going on. You may have other resource leaks.

Comment: @AlaaMasoud tried that, but got very small amount of usefull info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341250/windows-phone-profiler-heap-summary-shows-not-a-complete-summary

Comment: Where are you getting the pics from? And are you resizing them to 40x40 or is that their original size?

Comment: @AlaaMasoud Its their original size, they are stored on the server. No resizing.

What about list creation process, its quite simple. I'm sending server request, it answers me with json with names and links to images (using this cache http://kawagoe.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Storage.PersistentImageCache&referringTitle=Storage.ImageCache).

However, memory is just disappearing..

Comment: Its hard to tell what's going without seeing the code. But try and point your image controls to the URLs you get from the Json without using any third party libraries so you can at least narrow the possible causes.

Comment: @AlaaMasoud Just tried to turn off cache and check memory again. Results are pretty close to original: 39 MBytes for list with no images, 42 MBytes at the top of the list, 45 at the bottom. Without the list, it is 32 MBytes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looking like 20 MBs is too large for the list of simple items: http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.fi/2011/01/wp7-know-your-data.html

> The import information to take from the screenshot:
>
> Number of items in the collection = 378 Serialized size of collection
>   = 346,538 Bytes Average size of serialized item = 916 Bytes
>
> The current memory usage = 12,865,536 Bytes

So, something is definitely wrong with my app.